# Convert Numeric Variable into Time variable in R

Tags: r, time, character, numeric

I have the loading time in format of hh:mm [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EEJT.jpg). However when I read the data using read excel (readxl) it appeared as numeric [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQyxS.jpg). So I want to convert these values as time in hh:mm agian or is there any way to read this file without converting into numeric.

as.POSIXlt(0.2743)
Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(0.2743) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: What is equivalent "Time" value of 0.2743 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hms::hms`:

```r
library(hms)

hms(days = 0.2743)
#> 06:34:59.52

hms(days = 0.31597)
#> 07:34:59.808

hms(days = 1)
#> 24:00:00
```

An object of class `POSIXlt` also contains a date part, and if a numeric input is provided, we need to specify from which origin to start counting seconds, e.g.:

```r
## 1 minute from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
as.POSIXlt(60, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "1970-01-01 00:01:00 UTC"
```

---

Alternatively, if the output should be formatted as `hh:mm`, instead of `hh:mm:ss` as with the `hms` function, we could use `format` with `as.POSIXlt` and a dummy origin:

```r
format(as.POSIXlt(0.2743 * 3600 * 24, origin = Sys.Date(), tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M")
#> [1] "06:34"

format(as.POSIXlt(0.31597 * 3600 * 24, origin = Sys.Date(), tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M")
#> [1] "07:34"
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But that is not what I required. For example 0.31597 is equal to 7:35.

Comment: @KNReddy: see the edited the answer, where I changed hours to days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to represent in HH:MM no need of HH:MM:SS. For example, I just want hms(days = 0.31597)  as 07:34 instead of 07:34:59.808

Comment: also can you tell me to convert 5 DAYS 18H : 40M into hh:mm